# How do I create a function that can generically calculate product in any object's set of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm tasked with trying to create a function that will return the product of key value pairs of any given array.

```
function productOfValues(someObject) {
  //write your code here!
  **return [testObject.a * testObject.b * testObject.c];***
}

let testObject = {
  'a': 5, 
  'b': 12,
  'c': 3
}

productOfValues(testObject)
```

The asterisked line above indicates the code I've tried to implement, but it does not work. Additionally, to complete this question, I'm supposed to write the function more generically so that the function will calculate the product of *any* object created. Kind of lost here.

Comment: `return Object.values(someObject).reduce((p, c) => p * c, 1);`? (after short thought, the `, 1` is correct and necessary. On one side, empty objects won't cause a crash, on the other, prod_k=0^0 s_k = 1)

Comment: First of all, you have a confusion between your global variable `testObject` and your parameter `someObject`. Then, to calculate the product of any created object, you should try to loop through your object.

Comment: *typo: \prod_{k=1}^0 s_k = 1, empty product.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get all the values from your object using `Object.values()` and than just calculate the product using `Array.reduce()` of the values that you just got.

```js
const testObject = {
  'a': 5, 
  'b': 12,
  'c': 3
};

const calculateProductOfObjectValues = (obj) => {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return values.reduce((a,b) => a * b);
};

console.log(calculateProductOfObjectValues(testObject))
```